# Undo changes not in Photoshop history?

Tags: photoshop-cs5

I made a lot of changes to an image.  The second and about the eighth change was sharpen--again by mistake.  I wanted to delete the secons sharpen from the image, but by now, the history now no longer listed any of the changes.

I have noticed the history only displays a few changes and then only temporarily.  A co-worker said I had to start over.  Is this true?

Answer (score 1):

If you add more changes than your history is set to save then yes you will have to re-open the original file and start over.

The way to avoid this issue is to start taking **Snapshots** under the history panel before making a huge number of changes that way you can just click the snapshot and it will jump you back to the point you took it.

You can also increase the number of history states photoshop keeps under Preferences -> Performance. This will increase memory usage so make sure you have enough.